# In GNOME/gdk/gtkmm/cairo, a equivalent series of codes for MS Windows "TransparentBlt()"?

Tags: gnome, cairo, gtkmm, gdk

How can I port MFC

```
TotalDC.TransparentBlt(position.x, position.y, width, height, &image1DC, 0, 0, width, height, RGB(255, 255, 255));
```

to GNOME/gdk/gtkmm/cairo?

I know that MFC "BitBlt();" can be ported using

```
image1->copy_area(0,0,width,height,Total,position.x,position.y);
```

But this function does not designate the transparent RGB(r,g,b).

Comment: Please supplement the question post instead of writing in the comments so that it is more readable by future users.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.